# How to display the assigned document's name with Okular 0.19.3 in Kubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS?

Tags: kubuntu, pdf, okular

Okular is displaying wrong document name in the top bar.

**Example 1:**

[image: Wrong]

**Example 2:**

[image: Wrong]

And for some files it will display the correct name:

**Example 3:**

[image: Rigth]

How do I manage to get Okular to display the correct file name?.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution:

In Okular go to `Settings` menu and select the `Configure Okular` option.

Uncheck "*Display document title in titlebar if available*" option and hit <kbd>Apply</kbd> and then <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]