# How to change pdf title in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, pdf

> If you are hurrying to flag this question as a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356587/how-to-edit-a-pdf-file-in-kubuntu-13-04) or
>   [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162037/how-to-edit-pdfs) questions, please stop, the answers on those questions do not
>   provide an answer to the question here.

After I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591280/how-to-display-the-assigned-documents-name-with-okular-0-19-3-in-kubuntu-14-04) I found that title and file name are pretty much different, so then I tried changing the pdf document's title to whatever I want to?.

I tried with Okular, but it doesn't let me change the title, I also tried GIMP but it just don't seem to have the option. I even tried verifying the document properties with Dolphin and it does not work either. How to change the title then?.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/401114/81372. Also, make sure to check out [PDFMtEd](https://github.com/Glutanimate/PDFMtEd) for a GUI solution to editing PDF metadata.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Solution:

After a deep web search using Google, I found a tool called `pdftk` (Title in the manual: pdftk - A handy tool for manipulating PDF). To install the `pdftk` use the below line on the command line;

```
 sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

then created a file named `updateTitle.txt` containing the following information:

```
InfoKey: Title
InfoValue: New Title
```

And saved it in the same location the PDF is, then I ran in a terminal (in the PDF’s location):

```
pdftk input.pdf update_info updateTitle.txt output output.pdf
```

The PDF’s title is now "New Title".