# How to specify the title of the PDF file GS produces?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm using this

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sOutputFile=finished.pdf  file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf
```

to concatenate 3 PDF files, and `gs` inexplicably takes the title of one of them and uses it as the title of the new document (shown in the title bar by the PDF viewer). I wonder if the new title could be specified explicitly?

Comment: The 2 methods described here appear to work: [Where is metadata for PDF files? Can I insert metadata into any PDF file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489230/where-is-metadata-for-pdf-files-can-i-insert-metadata-into-any-pdf-file) . FYI it doesn't seem to be necessary to specify an entire `/DOCINFO` structure so for example `gs ... -sOutputFile=finished.pdf -f file1.pdf file2.pdf file3.pdf -c "[ /Title (My New Title) /DOCINFO pdfmark"`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks. This should probably be the answer?

Comment: Indeed, this is the answer. "After the fact", you can use exiftool to add/edit metadata on an already created PDF, https://askubuntu.com/questions/591289/how-to-automatically-set-the-pdf-title-tag-with-the-file-name?rq=1. Also pdftk: https://askubuntu.com/questions/591283/how-to-change-pdf-title-in-kubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1